# What non-precision approach in the US has the longest segment at MDA?

Tags: faa-regulations, instrument-procedures

What approach is the longest approach, in the US, which has the longest segment at the MDA?  Obviously this is for non-precision approaches.

Comment: Perhaps someplace with a really, really high MDA. Maybe Aspen or someplace like that where you need essentially VFR in order to expect to see the runway at MDA on a normal-ish descent? Interesting question.

Comment: The NDB/DME-A approach [at KSUN](http://airnav.com/airport/KSUN) has 5.2NM to fly visually from the MAP to the runway but I have no idea if that's the longest or not.

Comment: @Ralph J, actually, I was looking for low, but long MDA segments, but that was not the question.  My guess is that we will find 6 to perhaps 8 or 9 mile segments.  The answer to the normal question might be in TERPS, which I have not exhaustively searched yet.

Comment: Hmmm, don't have any solid answers. I'll toss out LDA 25 at KEGE http://155.178.201.160/d-tpp/1710/06403LDAD25.PDF as my effort, but I suspect others will find better answers than that.

Comment: That LDA  segment is over 7 miles. Great find, @RalphJ.  This will be a long search, or require some fancy data mining, unless someone has the right answers closer to their fingertips.